# Whiptail radiolist

Tags: iptables, whiptail

I am trying to build a iptables configure with whiptail. And I am stuck at the moment. I have got code below and I am trying to develop radio list where user choose between INPUT or OUPUT.

```
io=$(whiptail --title "Add rule" --radiolist "Choose" 20 40 15 \
"INPUT" "" ON \
"OUTPUT" "" OFF \
3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)

echo "$io"

exit
```

After this script is shown in whiptail screen I choose for ex. second option (OUTPUT) but I got result "INPUT". Also I am not able to shift an asterisk. I don't know If asterisk should be shifting or don't.

[image: Choosen OUTPUT but in command line is INPUT]

I appreaciate your help and have a nice day guys!

EDIT: SOLVED, USE SPACE BAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle the state of a `radiolist` item using the spacebar.  The state is shown with the asterisk (`*`). Simply moving the cursor up/down with cursor-keys has no effect on the selection.

Interestingly, the manual pages for [`whiptail`](http://www.manpages.spotlynx.com/gnu_linux/man/whiptail.1) and [`dialog`](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html) do not mention the detail of the *space-bar* for radio-lists.